# Game - Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

The following code starts a game in which the user has to type the given words before the time runs out. 
But my code is executing only once : it is generating the random word only once.
Can someone tell me why this is happening?

The level1, level2 ... are basically the levels of the game which will increase after every 3 letters of each level. The game is in its initial stage so the layout of the page is very basic.

```js
function words() {
  level1 = ["crackajack", "showbizzes", "mizzenmast", "kolkhoznik", "schnozzles", "skyjacking", "embezzlers",
    "jackknifed", "jackknives", "kibbutznik", "japanizing", "maximizing", "jarovizing", "cheapjacks",
    "equivoques", "lumberjack", "zigzaggers", "jackknifes", "jackhammer", "pozzolanaf", "highjacked"
  ];

  level2 = ["Alliteration", "Pennsylvania", "Exacerbation", "Independence", "Commensalism", "Intelligence",
    "Relationship", "Thanksgiving", "Professional", "Organization", "Abolitionist", "Onomatopoeia",
    "Appreciation", "Annunciation", "Malnutrition", "Architecture", "Biodiversity", "Acceleration",
    "Interdiction", "Communicator"
  ];

  level3 = ["Interjection05", "Exasperation91", "Felicitation39", "Abbreviation17", "Voluminosity13",
    "Colonization29", "Interception51", "Championship41", "Acquaintance10", "Depreciation16", "Refrigerator81",
    "Kaleidoscope12", "Neighborhood20", "Anticipation77", "Stridulation61", "Prescription57", "Condensation21",
    "Progesterone98", "Philadelphia19", "Pericarditis34", "Veterinarian12"
  ];

  level4 = ["!Interjection05", "@Exasperation91", "#Felicitation39", "$Abbreviation17", "%Voluminosity13",
    "^Colonization29", "&nterception51", "*Championship41", "(Acquaintance10", ")Depreciation16", "_Refrigerator81",
    "-Kaleidoscope12", "+Neighborhood20", "*Anticipation77", "/Stridulation61", "<Prescription57", ">Condensation21",
    "?Progesterone98", "{}Philadelphia19", "~Pericarditis34", ":Veterinarian12"
  ];
}

function generate() {
  var i;
  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    switch (i) { //for deciding the level of the gameplay
      case 1:
        name(level1);
        break;
      case 2:
        name(level2);
        break;
      case 3:
        name(level3);
        break;
      case 4:
        name(level4);
        break;
    }
  }
}

function name(arr) {
  var j, n;
  for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    var n = Math.floor((Math.random()) * 20);
    x = arr[n];
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML += x;
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.text = 'text';
    input.id = 'entry';
    var add = document.querySelector('#show');
    add.append(input);
    input.addEventListener('change', compare);
  }
}

function compare() {
  var y = document.getElementById("entry").value;
  if (x != y) {
    alert("You typed wrong text ");
    alert("Game Over");
  }
  return;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Typing tunnel</title>
</head>

<body onload='words();'>
  <div id="first">
    <h1 id="heading">TYPING TUNNEL</h1>
    <div id="show">
      <button id='start' onclick='generate();'>Play</button>
      <input type="text" id="entry" onchange='compare();'>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `compare()` doesn't do anything if they got the word correct.

Comment: First of all, you have to get rid of the errors in your code. See the added snippet. Neslon correct a typo already. Now, your next issue is that `x` is local to the name function. You can't read it inside the compare function.  Are you familiar with variables scope in JavaScript?

Comment: Also, this question is more suited for the [game dev stack exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), since it is a question about game logic (as the `game-development` tag on here suggests)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about game logic and should be asked on the game dev stack exchange site

Comment: I guess - but it's just a simple JavaScript coding problem. I recommend @Harsh start adding console.log statements through the code to understand what variables are there. Or, even better, take a look at: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/ and use a debugger to walk through the logic and understand where and why things are going wrong.

Comment: @  Guillaume Georges , sir i have declared x without the keyword var so the variable x automatically has a global scope